# Where does the $\log$ go in $\log\prod_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{1-x_it}=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j\geq 0}(x_it)^j?$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, formal-power-series

I'm reading some notes [here](http://www.ma.rhul.ac.uk/~uvah099/Maths/SymComb.pdf).

At the bottom of page 12, there is the equality
$$
\log\prod_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{1-x_it}=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j\geq 0}(x_it)^j.
$$

I know the formal identity 
$$
\frac{1}{1-x_it}=\sum_{j\geq 0}(x_it)^j
$$
but where did the $\log$ go on the right hand side? I thought a $\log$ or a product is the sum of the $\log$ of the terms.

Comment: It should go between the two sums.

Comment: @SquirtleSquad So it's a typo, yes?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that this starts from  $$\log\prod_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{1-x_it}=-\sum_{i=1}^m\log(1-x_it)$$ followed by Taylor expansion $$\log(1-a)=-\sum_ {j=1}^\infty \frac {a^j}j\implies \log(1-x_it)=-\sum_ {j=1}^\infty \frac {(x_it)^j}j$$ So, $$\log\prod_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{1-x_it}=-\sum_{i=1}^m\log(1-x_it)=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_ {j=1}^\infty \frac {(x_it)^j}j=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_ {j=1}^\infty \frac {(x_i)^j}j t^j$$